# apk expansion file not downloading from playstore

Tags: android, expansion

I am working with the sample apk expansion file downloaded from the SDk. My main expansion file is about 5 MB of size and its format is `"main.1.mypackage_name"` .

I uploaded my app in play store as a draft application along with the expansion file.But the issue is when the expansion file download progress,one folder is created with the package name under **"Android/obb/mypackage"**. But there is no such file inside that folder.

Sometimes i am getting `STATE_FAILED_UNLICENSED` message from playstore while the download begins.

What should be the reason of this ? Anything wrong with the file name format or something ?  Can anybody help me.

Comment: The file name should be `main.1.mypackage_name.obb`

Comment: .obb extension is automatically added by playstore right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According Goole Play for Developers..

> Please note that package names for apk files are unique and permanent,
>   so please choose wisely. Package names cannot be deleted or re-used in
>   the future. Keep in mind that if you've lost your keystore, you'll
>   have to publish the app with a new package name and a new key. You
>   should also update the description of the original app and unpublish
>   it.

These 2 links may help you..

- [Upload Applications](http://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=113469)
- [APK expansion Files](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html)(See **Downloading the Expansion Files** point here)

Comment: actually with the same application, i am uploading different apk's with different version number following deactivating the old one..The application is a draft one..

Answer (score 0):

In the Google play Developer console there is an area to add gmail accounts which can receive license responses for testing purposes, you can also change the license response. This can be found in the 'Edit Profile' link (of the old design) or the 'Settings' (in the new design).

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes..i already added test accounts and change the license response too..but no results..everytime a folder is created with package name(under ~Android/obb)..

Answer (score 0):

**May help the below solutions:-**

Check tag is added in manifest.xml

```
        <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE"/>
```

Check added all libaray and all the classes in project:-

```
        com.google.android.vending.licensing.
```

Check licence key added to the project from google play store accoount.

Check Uploaded folder with below format.

```
       main.1.mypackage_name.obb.zip
```

Thanks!!